# asp.net-mvc jquery adding multiple number of partial views

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

My problem seems very common to me, and I thought I could find an answer online, but I couldn't.

I have a drop down list, and based on the selected value, I need to have multiple partial Views. (one selection can have none, the other one have 3, etc.)

I have a partial View that gets a "DriveDetail" object and I need to load multiple number of these partial Views Dynamically using JQuery.

So far I have:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "TestInput/getTestStationInformation2/" + testStation,
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'post',
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $('#driveDetailDiv').append(data[i]);
            }
        }
    });
```

I can either return an IEnumerable or List of those Drives.

```
public JsonResult getTestStationInformation(long id)
{
    IEnumerable<DriveDetails> aa = repository.listDriveInfo(id);
    return Json(aa);
}

public JsonResult getTestStationInformation2(long id)
{
    List<PartialViewResult> res = new List<PartialViewResult>();
    List<DriveDetails> aa = repository.listDriveInfo(id).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < aa.Count(); i++)
    {
        res.Add(PartialView("DriveDetailsPartial", aa[i]));
    }

    return Json(res);
}
```

but none of these work.

I have:

```
$.get('<%= Url.Action("Details","TestInput", null) %>', function (tmp) {
    $('#driveDetailDiv').append(tmp);
});
```

in my code, but instead of null, I need to send data[0], and get the partialView of data[0]. but I don't know how to send data[0]. When I try

```
 new {id = data[0])
```

I get an error, and when I try to use the second Action, which returns a list of PartialViews, it doesn't show up when I try to append them.

Comment: Do you mean that you might return a partial view multiple times based on a list of similar items?

Comment: I just saw your comment Lost dreamer. I fixed the problem, I should've used post instead of get.

but now I need to somehow get the data of each partial view, and update model. (each partial view is based on an item, and I want to update all the items)